# The data(number) I append to DataFrame using panda

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I built a CNN prediction model to do the prediction. And I append the result to a DataFrame as pic show. However, why does my prediction column has 2 brackets [[]] around my data? How to get rid of it and show the number only?

```
test_img = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/Circle_Cropped_test_images/*.jpg'
Test_Path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/Circle_Cropped_test_images'
Name = []
result = []
for name in os.listdir(Test_Path):
    Name.append(name[0:-5])
for img in glob.glob(test_img):
    prediction = model.predict(prepare(img))
    result.append(prediction)
Temp = {'File Name':Name, 'Prediction':result}
temp = pd.DataFrame(Temp)
temp
```

[image]

So After I change the result.append(prediction) to result.append(prediction[0])

```
test_img = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/Circle_Cropped_test_images/*.jpg'
Test_Path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/GF_BSIF/Circle_Cropped_test_images'
Name = []
result = []
for name in os.listdir(Test_Path):
    Name.append(name[0:-5])
for img in glob.glob(test_img):
    prediction = model.predict(prepare(img))
    result.append(prediction[0])
Temp = {'File Name':Name, 'Prediction':result}
temp = pd.DataFrame(Temp)
temp
```

The DataFrame shows 1 bracket left.
Any way to remove the bracket?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems your prediction is 2d array, can you print the return type and value of model.predict(). like below:

```
print(type(prediction))
print(prediction)
```

Comment: It still has 1 bracket left on the DataFrame, any way to remove it? Thank you.

Comment: update the answer, try to print return type and value of model.predict() first

Comment: I sort it out! Thank you!!

Comment: can you upvote my answer